# Dependency Injection with Dagger2, how to get context

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm learning dependency injection with Dagger2.

I created a HttpRequester class that has a get method and returns some data from a server.

This is my code:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
HttpRequester httpRequester;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getHttpRequester();

    httpRequester.get("http://url.to.get.the.data", new HttpRequester.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataRetrieved(String result) {

            Log.d("App", "Result: " + result);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop () {
    super.onStop();
    if (httpRequester != null) {

        httpRequester.cancelAll();
    }
}

void getHttpRequester() {

    HttpRequesterComponent httpRequesterComponent = DaggerHttpRequesterComponent.builder().httpRequesterModule(new HttpRequesterModule()).build();

    httpRequester = httpRequesterComponent.provideHttpRequester();
}
}
```

HttpRequesterModule

```
@Module
public class HttpRequesterModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    HttpRequester provideHttpRequester(Context context){

        return new HttpRequester(context);
    }
}
```

HttpRequesterComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {HttpRequesterModule.class})
public interface HttpRequesterComponent {

    HttpRequester provideHttpRequester();
}
```

HttpRequester

```
public class HttpRequester {

    Context context;

    public HttpRequester(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public interface Listener {

        void onDataRetrieved(String result);
    }

    private RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    public static final String TAG = "TAG";

    public void get(String url, final Listener listener){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String res) {

                        listener.onDataRetrieved(res);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        stringRequest.setTag(TAG);

        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void cancelAll() {

        queue.cancelAll(TAG);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call httpRequester.get() I get a NullPointerException since the context is null. I want to know how to inject the context. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to notice that you never initialize the context attribute con HttpRequester. Receive a `Context` in your constructor so it has a value:

```
public class HttpRequester {

    Context context;

    public HttpRequester(Context context) {
        this.context = context
    }

    ...
}
```

After that, you just have to provide it in your `HttpRequesterModule`:

```
@Module
public class HttpRequesterModule {

    private final Context context;

    public HttpRequesterModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    HttpRequester provideHttpRequester(Context context){
        return new HttpRequester(context);
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Now you just have to pass a Context to your module

Comment: I added the contructor to the HttpRequester class and modified the HttpRequesterModule. I edidted the original question. Now I'm getting                                                   "Error:(17, 19) error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
daggertutorial.modules.HttpRequesterModule.provideHttpRequester(android.content.Context context)
[parameter: android.content.Context context]". I'm I missing something on the HttpRequesterModule class?

Comment: Yes, you are. Dagger 2 has no way of providing a `Context` object for your `HttpRequester`. I'll update my answer